# Exec nodejs and get output on error

Tags: node.js, go, error-handling, exec, testcafe

I am trying to fire a command via exec in my go binary to get JSON output of the other script. The other script is a nodejs task checking for html problems.
If I fire the nodeJS task on cli everything works fine and I get JSON output, but if I fire the command inside of go I only get:

> exit status 1

I am not total sure if the problem is a nodejs or a go problem, but even if nodejs founds HTML Problems I want to be able to analyze the JSON Response in my go script.

Here is my source code:

```
out, err := exec.Command("/usr/bin/testcafe", "'chromium:headless --no-sandbox'", "--reporter json", "/data/checks.js").Output()
status := http.StatusOK
message := ""
if err != nil {
    status = http.StatusNotImplemented
    message = err.Error() + string(string(out[:]))
    fmt.Println(message)
}
```

Comment: Arguments are separate elements in the slice. So you should have `"--reporter",  "json"`, and maybe the same with `chromium...` unless you really want a quoted string.

Comment: And as mentioned in the [Cmd.Output docs](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.Output), you should check the `ExitError.Stderr`. I'm guessing that will tell you something about unknown or invalid arguments.

Comment: What does your actual command prints in terminal?

Comment: Why do you apply `string` twice in `string(string(out[:]))`?

Comment: How do you write the command on the terminal?

Comment: @Marc this is exactly what the Problem was. I needed to TypeCast this ExitError.Stderr which is not good documentated...

The missing Line was:

    message += string(err.(*exec.ExitError).Stderr[:])

I also separeted reporter and json, but needed to have this quoted string as one arguments.

Thanks also to md2perpe, this was just some kind of tryout, is cleaned up in the code now!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above if you ever need to access Stderr from an Command Exit in Golang use:

```
message += string(err.(*exec.ExitError).Stderr[:])
```

In my case the nodejs tool gave an exit code based on the amounts of problems. Solved this it runs perfectly now =).

Answer (score 1):

I made a function that I use to do shell command execution: 
https://gist.github.com/leninhasda/8f2b5cdc22677a8f2bdf2e896eb0b561

```
stdOut, stdErr, err := ShellExec("echo", "hello", "world")
if err != nil {
    // error executing command
}

if stdErr != "" {
    // shell command returned error message
}

if stdOut != "" {
    // shell command returned output message
    // hello world
}
```